# Switching between different servers in postgresql sql shell command

Tags: postgresql

Since I am new to postgresql shell command lines, I am very much confused on switch between servers, databases. First, I have logged in using default values in shellSql window. It is opening second server in my pgadmin server lists(in order). But my question here is how to switch between different servers through shell commands?
Example: If I have 3 servers (postgresql9, postgresql11 and remote servers).

Comment: `\connect` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS

Comment: and use `\conninfo` to check where you are currently connected to, see: `\?` for more options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is directly given in documentation
[PSQL-META-COMMANDS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS)

**Examples:**

```
=> \c mydb myuser host.dom 6432
=> \c service=foo
=> \c "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mydb connect_timeout=10 sslmode=disable"
=> \c postgresql://tom@localhost/mydb?application_name=myapp
```